# Image files not being read on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimage

This one has me confounded, so I'll try to go through the chronology so someone smart than I am can show me where I'm going wrong.

Everything was working perfectly on my app, both on the device and on the simulator. I have an image file, myimage.png, that is located in the directory where my project is and has been added to the project. It shows up in XCode and everything.

I build, run, and things work as planned.

Then I decided to get clever in photoshop and spruce up my image with a bit more color. In the finder, I deleted myimage.png from the directory where my project is located. Then I saved the new image as myimage.png in that very same directory. Back in XCode, the file shows up in the project and looks just as nice as planned.

I build, run, and no image shows up. WTF??!?

Here are my two questions, in order of importance:

1. How do I fix this so that my image shows up again?
2. What have a done wrong in this process?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the code where I am calling the image. In myViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     // SOME CODE THAT DOES OTHER THINGS UNRELATED TO imageView
     [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"]];
     // MORE CODE THAT DOES OTHER THINGS UNRELATED TO imageView
}
```

ANOTHER EDIT: ***Not one single character of my code changed between the app working and not working.*** I appreciate all of the suggestions since I clearly cannot figure this one out on my own, but the problem is most likely not with the code.

Comment: The iphone is case sensitive. You must write the image name exactly.

Comment: This is not the issue, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. easy: in xCode delete the file reference *and the files themselves* and then import it again...
2. mhm... when you changed your image was xCode opened? it may have seen somehow it's been deleted and lost the link... if you change it xCode could "choose" to NOT include it in the target mainBundle when you build your project... in xCode select the file and see if the checkMark on target is selected:

[image]

if not it won't be included in you app (and this answers to your n:1 question too)...

maybe a better way to add a resource files which could be probably be modified by other programs in future while yourProject could be opened (i do it with an html site to be included, jpg and gif too) is to put them in a subFolder of your project and then add all that folder to your xCode project AND in the dialog window choose:

"create folder references..."

[image]

that will create a blue folder in xCode and all its contents will refresh automatically if you change, add, delete files or subfolder inside it...

**BUT** remember that the subFolders will exist in the same tree-order in your app mainBundle, so if you need to load a .png you need to specify where to find it.

**PS**
check also that the file name is exactly the same of the old file, including UpperCase chars
("a" != "A")

Comment: @PengOne; mhm... and your code worked well before... and you didn't change it? then.. sure you exported your png in the right way (it may not be a png, but just its extension)... just guessing... try to change the fileName in xCode and in your code...

Comment: I've changed your answer to 1 to the solution that worked for me since it was so close... I had to delete the files as well as the reference. Odd, but it worked. Thanks for helping on this!

Answer (score 0):

I think that happens because Xcode doesn't know that the file has changed. Always add/remove files in the project navigator.

It should work if you **clean** your project and build again.

Comment: XCode can "see" the new file in the sense that when I select under "Groups & Files" on the left hand side, the image that shows up is the new image. I tried cleaning and even deleting the build directory, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a Build -> Clean. And the rebuild.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work. I even deleted the build directory. No luck.

Comment: Yes, but I doubt it will help. I'll edit my question to include it.

Comment: Also try removing the image and re-adding it using xcode. Obviously, don't tick the box to delete the file totally. Just remove from project.